# mysql post missing data from SERVER REQUEST_METHOD

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have the following code, whenever I try to insert the data, the `$content` is not being inserted, where might the problem be? I am using the function test input for security related issues.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$title = $content = $path = $file_type ="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  $title = test_input($_POST["title"]);
  $content = test_input($_POST["content"]);
  $path = test_input($_POST["path"]);
  $file_type = test_input($_POST["file_type"]);

}

function test_input($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","---","---","---");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$sql="INSERT INTO articles (ArtID,Title,Content,Image_VideoLink_Path,file_type)
VALUES
('','$title','$content','$path',' $file_type')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "<h2 >Article Published</h2>";
echo"<a href='../mag/index.php'> View it Now </a>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

here is the code for the form:

```
<form  method="POST" action="artPro.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create New Article</legend>
    <br/>
    Article Title:
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter title here" class="span3" name="title" required>

           Image/Video Path :

           <input type="text" placeholder="enter image name e.g k.jpg or k.mp4 for video" name="path" class="span3" required/>

          File Type :
          <input type="text" name="file_type" class="span3" required placeholder="e.g: image or video"/>

  <br/>

            <label>Article Content:</label>

           <textarea name="content" rows="20"  class="jqte-test span12" required   id="txtmsg"></textarea>


<br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Publish</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Could we see your form? Or method of posting data?

Comment: before running `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` can you run `echo $sql` and post  the output in your question

Comment: here is what am getting form the echo $sql INSERT INTO articles (Title,Content,Image_VideoLink_Path,file_type) VALUES ('benb','','rr.jpg',' image')

Comment: @Jamie Taylor i have included the form now,you can check it

Comment: Everything seems to be in order there too, very strange

Comment: am using the jquery-te editor for the textarea,when i echo $content on  using $_POST on nxt page its working,but can just insert in database

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

> $sql="INSERT INTO articles
>   (Title,Content,Image_VideoLink_Path,file_type) VALUES
>   ('$title','$content','$path',' $file_type')";

$content was not being inserted because you are giving Article ID. And I am sure that Article ID will your primary key and this will auto incremented. So, you did not need to mention Article id in sql query (statement).

Comment: i tried changing but when i echo $sql i get this :  INSERT INTO articles (Title,Content,Image_VideoLink_Path,file_type) VALUES ('benb','','rr.jpg',' image')

Comment: Why you echo $sql? You need to run query in order to insert into database. If $sql is giving you values as you typed then $sql is correct.

You just need to run query. You can run query like this:
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }